# How do I get data out of iOS Combine closure

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I'm trying to get dowloaded data into the audioArray variable for use elsewhere, but it keeps returning nil if I try to use it in another function.

```
var audioArray: [String] = []

func listFiles(){
    
    var tempArray: [String] = []

        let storageOperation = Amplify.Storage.list()
        resultSink = storageOperation.resultPublisher.sink {
                if case let .failure(storageError) = $0 {
                    print("Failed: \(storageError.errorDescription). \(storageError.recoverySuggestion)")
                }
            }

        receiveValue: { [self] listResult in
                print("Completed")
                listResult.items.forEach { item in
                    
                    tempArray.append(item.key)

                    audioArray = tempArray
                    
                    print(self.audioArray)
                    
                }

            }

    }
```

Comment: Read this - It may help http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Comment: first check if your item.key has a value . Then you can directly append self.audioArray.append(item.key)